# Delete old self-hosted VSTS build agent _work folders

Tags: azure-devops, build-agent, resource-cleanup

We have a self-hosted TFS build agent which has run out of space so I would like to delete as many of the folders under the `agent\_work` and `agent_dply\_work` folders as possible, where they are > 1 month old.

Is this safe to do?

I have found [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/708) on setting up cleaning, which I will certainly do.

Also found [this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1895) on cleaning the `_work` folder which recommends renaming, then deleting the whole folder, but not parts of it.

What I can't find is the `maintenance settings` for the agent pool, as described in [this post](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2017/05/06/maintenance-for-build-agent-in-tfs-build/). I'm wondering if this is in some control panel on the actual agent, because it does not appear to be in our settings. I looks for it under Project > Project Settings > Agent pools, for example:

`https://COMPANY.visualstudio.com/PROJECT/_settings/agentqueues`

Comment: Yes, it's safe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's safe to do this. Besides I would recommend you follow suggestion mentioned by *TingluoHuang*  in second link.

Just need pay attention to follow:

> Make sure there is no running job on the agent and stop the agent
> process/service first before delete/rename any folder

Actually, there is a setting related to configuring reoccurring maintenance (Organization Settings -> Agent Pools -> <`Pool Name`>-> Settings [tab]).

[image]

And then you could find related sett

You need first turn off Maintenance job. And then you will find related setting there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I have looked everywhere for that setting and can't see it. I'm not an admin in our system, however.

Comment: same here, I am unable to find this setting !

Comment: @MattW : this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#what-is-a-maintenance-job helped me , this option is available under organization settings, not under project settings ! I was under project settings.

Comment: Agree not easy to find. Go to the absolute root for your TFS, eg. https://company123.visualstudio.com/ then look at the very bottom left corner of the screen for `Organization settings`. Then click `Agent pools` on the left and `Settings` on top.